# Proper way to implement mouse events

Tags: java, swing

I have code, it's below, that displays a photograph in the JPanel.  Actually, the JPanel is walking through a photo album and I have it so that when the JPanel is clicked on, the panel advances to the next frame.  I also have it configured so that if the JPanel is right-clicked on, a popup menu is displayed.

I read that, when implementing a popup menu, one needs to override both mousePressed() and mouseReleased() in order to catch the trigger for all platforms.  However, since I have a listener associated with the JPanel, when the user clicks the window the JPanel advances two photos.  This is understandable, but how should I code this so that I ensure I display the popup on all platforms (my professor may check my program on Linux and I have to code it on Windows at home).

Answer (score 3):

JComponents have a property componentPopupMenu - setting that property makes your popupMenu appear automatically, without requiring any effort in a MouseListener

```
 photoPanel.setComponentPopupMenu(photoPopupMenu);
```

Then make sure that your mouse-triggered action (advancing to the next) happens only on single left pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger()
```

to determine if for the platform the given event should be used to show the popup.

You would put this in each method (mousePressed and mouseReleased)

Comment: no, waaay too low-level: as a general rule, always go for the highest abstraction available